# No client-side caching in headless Chrome with proxy-server?

Tags: proxy, cache, google-chrome

(I think this has more to do with software configuration than programming which is why I posted here instead of StackOverflow.)

I've been testing and searching for a couple days it seems on this issue and haven't found a solution. I'm automating Chrome via [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) (specifically with Selenium in Python) and specifying both `--proxy-server` and `--user-data-dir`. When I launch Chrome normally this works fine and I see a `Cache` directory appear with new files. However, if I launch Chrome headless then *no* cache directory or files appear.

The proxy server is my own local [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) server and so I can see the traffic, or at least the tunnels opened for TLS/SSL, per domain. The number of connections for external resources is the same even when visiting the same page twice which tells me that it's not actually loading anything from the cache regardless of whether headless mode is used or not.

My question: is it possible to configure (headless) Chrome in a way that utilizes a client-side cache when a proxy server is being used? And if so, how?

P.S. -- The ultimate goal here is to be able to use headless Chrome with an authenticated proxy, something which can't be done in headless Chrome itself and thus I've resorted to Squid in the middle with a `cache_peer` configured. The problem with Squid there is that it cannot cache the HTTPS traffic and that's what most websites are on these days.

Comment: Squid is perfectly capable of caching https traffic and will do so for any web site which has marked its content as cacheable. By default content served by https is considered not cacheable (unlike http, which is considered public by default) so the remote server must send appropriate Cache-Control headers, but many https sites don't.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have not been able to get Squid to cache https content although it has cached http fine. All of the https content gets logged with "TCP_TUNNEL" even for content which I've verified to have cache-friendly response headers. If I'm wrong then you may want to add your 2 cents to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725987

Comment: Well if you're tunnelling TCP through it, then of course it can't cache anything.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sorry, I am not a Squid expert and I have not figured out how to get it to behave as I would like. That's the point of all these Q&A sites because other people are trying to figure out the same things. If I can discover the secrets of Squid then I can write some good answers and put a lot of the mystery to rest.